# OSQA apache memory footprint

Tags: apache, memory-leaks, server-configuration, osqa

I have an OSQA (python / django q&a application) installation serving 8 different sites. The sites are all in development, receiving minimal traffic. The server is a virtual private server with 512 mb of ram.

Apache is only serving dynamic pages with mod_wsgi behind Nginx. I can't stop Apache consuming more and more memory with each request until the server chokes.

I experimented with the configuration parameters without much luck to minimize the memory footprint. With the following mpm_prefork parameters in apache2.conf:

```
StartServers          2
MinSpareServers       1
MaxSpareServers       4
MaxClients            4
MaxRequestsPerChild 100
```

2 apache processes start using 4 mb and after the first request there are 4 processes with each nearly 50 mb and with each new request those 4 processes climb steadily up to nearly 200 mb each.

I feel like there is something wrong going on. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
KeepAlive Off
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 3
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 2

WSGIDaemonProcess osqaWSGI processes=2 python-path=/web/osqa_server:/web/osqa_server/lib/python2.6 threads=1 maximum-requests=550
WSGIProcessGroup osqaWSGI
```

Ran httperf against this with 10,000 concurrent hits and it was still standing.

Comment: did you mean MinSpareServers instead of MinSpareThreads? because MinSpareThreads is not recognized.

Comment: Depends on if you're working with prefork or worker.  MinSpareServers means you're using prefork.  See http://www.camelrichard.org/apache-prefork-vs-worker

Comment: thanks, it looks better now. yet i am a bit confused. after adding WSGIDaemonProcess part, now there are 4 processes right from the start. does the processes=2 have sth related to the number of processors? what would be the optimum for a 4 processor machine?